# Android - Position map to show custom route overlay

Tags: android, maps, overlay, routes

I have a custom overlay that basically draws a route from a list of co-ordinates onto a map. This all works fine but I need the map, when it first loads, to set its position and zoom level so it fits the route into the mapview control.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

Firstly I needed to find the min and max, lat and long coordinates of my route.

With these I could set the centre like so:

```
centerPoint = new GeoPoint((int)((minLat+((maxLat-minLat)/2))* 1e6), (int)((minLon+((maxLon-minLon)/2))* 1e6));
mController.setCenter(centerPoint);
```

and set the zoom level like so:

```
mController.zoomToSpan((int)((maxLat - minLat)* 1e6), (int)((maxLon - minLon)* 1e6));
```